# PyTorch: purpose of addmm function

Tags: pytorch

What is the purpose of the following PyTorch function ([doc](http://pytorch.org/docs/0.3.1/torch.html#torch.addmm)):

```
torch.addmm(beta=1, mat, alpha=1, mat1, mat2, out=None)
```

More specifically, is there any reason to prefer this function instead of just using

```
beta * mat + alpha * (mat1 @ mat2)
```

Answer (score 7):

The `addmm` function is an optimized version of the equation `beta*mat + alpha*(mat1 @ mat2)`. I ran some tests and timed their execution.

- If `beta=1, alpha=1`, then the execution of both the statements (`addmm` and manual) is approximately the same (`addmm` is just a little faster), regardless of the matrices size.
- If `beta` and `alpha` are not 1, then `addmm` is two times faster than the manual execution for smaller matrices (with total elements in order of 10<sup>5</sup>). But, if matrices are large (in order of 10<sup>6</sup>), the speedup seems negligible (`39ms` v/s `41ms`)

Comment: This answer would be x10 better if it had the code you used to time the functions