# Pytorch Linear Layer now automatically reshape the input?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I remember in the past, `nn.Linear` only accepts 2D tensors.

But today, I discover that `nn.Linear` now accepts 3D, or even tensors with arbitrary dimensions.

```
X = torch.randn((20,20,20,20,10))
linear_layer = nn.Linear(10,5)
output = linear_layer(X)
print(output.shape)
>>> torch.Size([20, 20, 20, 20, 5])
```

When I check the documentation for Pytorch, it does say that it now takes

> Input: :math:`(N, *, H_{in})` where :math:`*` means any number of
>             additional dimensions and :math:`H_{in} = \text{in\_features}`

So it seems to me that Pytorch `nn.Linear` now reshape the input by `x.view(-1, input_dim)` automatically.

But I cannot find any `x.shape` or `x.view` in the [source code](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear):

```
class Linear(Module):
    __constants__ = ['bias']

    def __init__(self, in_features, out_features, bias=True):
        super(Linear, self).__init__()
        self.in_features = in_features
        self.out_features = out_features
        self.weight = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features, in_features))
        if bias:
            self.bias = Parameter(torch.Tensor(out_features))
        else:
            self.register_parameter('bias', None)
        self.reset_parameters()

    def reset_parameters(self):
        init.kaiming_uniform_(self.weight, a=math.sqrt(5))
        if self.bias is not None:
            fan_in, _ = init._calculate_fan_in_and_fan_out(self.weight)
            bound = 1 / math.sqrt(fan_in)
            init.uniform_(self.bias, -bound, bound)

    @weak_script_method
    def forward(self, input):
        return F.linear(input, self.weight, self.bias)

    def extra_repr(self):
        return 'in_features={}, out_features={}, bias={}'.format(
            self.in_features, self.out_features, self.bias is not None
        )
```

Can anyone confirms this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`torch.nn.Linear` uses `torch.nn.functional.linear` function under the hood, that's where the operations are taking places (see [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.linear)).

It looks like this (removed docstrings and decorators for brevity):

```
def linear(input, weight, bias=None):
    if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
        # fused op is marginally faster
        ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
    else:
        output = input.matmul(weight.t())
        if bias is not None:
            output += bias
        ret = output
    return ret
```

**First case is [`addmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.addmm), which implements `beta*mat + alpha*(mat1 @ mat2)`** and is supposedly faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609226/pytorch-purpose-of-addmm-function) for example).

**Second operation is [`matmul`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul)**, and as one can read in their [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.matmul) it performs various operations based on the shape of tensors provided (five cases, not going to copy them blatantly here).

In summary it preserves dimensions between first `batch` and last `features dimension`. No `view()` is used whatsoever, especially not this `x.view(-1, input_dim)`, check the code below:

```
import torch

tensor1 = torch.randn(10, 3, 4)
tensor2 = torch.randn(10, 4, 5)

print(torch.matmul(tensor1, tensor2).shape)
print(torch.matmul(tensor1, tensor2).view(-1, tensor1.shape[1]).shape)
```

which gives:

```
torch.Size([10, 3, 5]) # preserves input's 3
torch.Size([50, 3]) # destroys the batch even
```