# Breaking down a batch in pytorch leads to different results, why?

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, batch-processing

I was trying something with batch processing in pytorch. In my code below, you may think of `x` as a batch of batch size 2 (each sample is a 10d vector). I use `x_sep` to denote the first sample in `x`.

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(10,10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        return x

f = net()

x = torch.randn(2,10)
print(f(x[0])==f(x)[0])
```

Ideally, `f(x[0])==f(x)[0]` should give a tensor with all true entries. But the output on my computer is

```
tensor([False, False,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True, False])
```

Why does this happen? Is it a computational error? Or is it related to how the batch precessing in implemented in pytorch?

---

**Update:** I simplified the code a bit. The question remains the same.

**My reasoning:**
I believe `f(x)[0]==f(x[0])` should have all its entries `True` because the law of matrix multiplication says so. Let us think of `x` as a 2x10 matrix, and think of the linear transformation `f()` as represented by matrix `B` (ignoring the bias for a moment). Then `f(x)=xB` by our notations. The law of matrix multiplication tells us that `xB` is equal to **first multiply the two rows by `B` on the right separately, and then put the two rows back together**. Translated back to the code, it is `f(x[0])==f(x)[0]` and `f(x[1])==f(x)[1]`.

Even if we consider the bias, every row should have the same bias and the equality should still hold.

Also note that no training is done here. Hence how the weights are initialized shouldn't matter.

Comment: Your last layer return receive 10 feature vector and return a 10 feature vector.  So what is the problem and where you are using batch exactly?

Comment: @Green Suppose I define a sample to be a vector of 10 components. Then you can think of `x` here as a batch of 2 samples, and `x_sep` is the first sample in `x`. Applying the linear transformation to `x` you get `y`, a batch of size 2. Shouldn't `y[0]` be equal to `f(x_sep)==y_sep` here? But my results tell me no, why?

Comment: @Green Or loosely speaking, why doesn't `f(x[0])==f(x)[0]` hold?

Comment: I answered you in detail. Hope it is clear for you now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

Under the hood it uses a function named `addmm` that have some optimizations, and probably multiply the vectors in a slightly different way

---

I just understood what was the **real** issue, and I edited the answer.

After trying to reproduce and debug it on my machine.
I found out that:

```
f(x)[0].detach().numpy()
>>>array([-0.5386441 ,  0.4983463 ,  0.07970242,  0.53507525,  0.71045876,
        0.7791027 ,  0.29027492, -0.07919329, -0.12045971, -0.9111403 ],
      dtype=float32)
f(x[0]).detach().numpy()
>>>array([-0.5386441 ,  0.49834624,  0.07970244,  0.53507525,  0.71045876,
        0.7791027 ,  0.29027495, -0.07919335, -0.12045971, -0.9111402 ],
      dtype=float32)
f(x[0]).detach().numpy() == f(x)[0].detach().numpy()
>>>array([ True, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
   False])
```

If you give a close look, you will find out that all the indices which are False, there is a slight numeric change in 5th floating point.

After some more debugging, I saw in the linear function it uses `addmm`:

```
def linear(input, weight, bias=None):
    if input.dim() == 2 and bias is not None:
        # fused op is marginally faster
        ret = torch.addmm(bias, input, weight.t())
    else:
        output = input.matmul(weight.t())
    if bias is not None:
        output += bias
    ret = output
return ret
```

**When addmm [`addmm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.addmm),  implements `beta*mat + alpha*(mat1 @ mat2)`** and is supposedly faster (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49609226/pytorch-purpose-of-addmm-function) for example).

[Credit to Szymon Maszke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57138540/pytorch-linear-layer-now-automatically-reshape-the-input/57143017#57143017)

Comment: It seems like a precision thing. What feels weird is that: Why would adding a second row affect the result of the first row? Does pytorch (maybe also numpy) use the information from the second row when it computes the output of the first row? Why would it do that...

Comment: Interesting discovery. But it seems that this phenomena is not specific to tensors of dim 2. Trying it with `x=torch.randn(2,10,10)` and then outputting `f(x[0][0])==f(x)[0][0]` still gives partly `True` and partly `False`. Although, the difference `f(x[0][0])-f(x)[0][0]` is rather small, approximately `1e-7` for the components that don't agree.