# why pytorch matric multiplication make mistake?

Tags: pytorch, matrix-multiplication

```
import torch
Q = torch.rand((16,128)).cuda()
K = torch.rand((128,10)).cuda()
QK = (Q @ K)[:1]
_QK = Q[:1] @ K
error = QK - _QK
print(error.sum().item())
```

The output is

```
-0.000331878662109375
```

Mathematically, QK and _QK should be strictly equal, why here they are different ?

Comment: Trying on CPU returns expected value... related to floating-point precision on Cuda perhaps?

Comment: @Stace Zhou you could try deterministic CUDA mode and verify the results, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/randomness.html)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/61292150/11790637